AGPBI - java.lang.SafeVarargs present as both library and non-library class
I have a Android Gradle build that gives the following warning for every build flavour.
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The following library types, prefixed by java., are present both as library and non library classes: java.lang.SafeVarargs. Library classes will be ignored.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
The following library types, prefixed by java., are present both as library and non library classes: java.lang.SafeVarargs. Library classes will be ignored.

I can't find java.lang.SafeVarargs in any of the library dependencies. So I don't understand what is being complained about.
The build and app work fine, but the warning is clogging up the build and I am concerned that I will miss a real warning. So I would like to know how to either

Resolve the issue causing the warning
Hide the warning


It is entirely unclear which dependencies you're even talking about, while @SafeVarargs is an annotation. One can ignore that warning, which only hints for the existence of two instances of that class. R8/D8 are capable of producing lots of log spam, one warning is almost as good as no warning.

So how do I remove just the warning for the @SafeVarargs annotation? Re deps, all the libraries that my app depends upon as well as their transitive dependencies.
